# Nginx El Capitan ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: macos, nginx, php-7

I Have installed Nginx-full via homebrew to the latests stable 1.8.1 version. I have installed php7.0 via brew as well. I want to get php working but i can't first get nginx to serve a static file. I have this configuration on a server and works perfectly but on my mac I'm having trouble. I set up my sites directory as follows:

nginx.conf:

```
#user  www-data www-data;
worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /Users/londreblocker/Developer/Sites/bootstrap;
    index index.php

    error_log /Users/londreblocker/Logs/DMFA_erros.log;
    access_log 

    /Users/londreblocker/Logs/DMFA_access.log;
}
```

there is a symbolic link to default in the sites-enabled folder. When i try to connect all i get is

> This webpage is not available
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Any idea what could be going wrong. I am on a mac with El Capitan.

Comment: Check if port 80 is open, not binded twice by IPv6 and served by nginx.

Comment: @AlekseyDeryagin How do i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if nginx configuration is correct:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

and your config symlinks not broken:

```
ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Check if nginx running:

```
ps aux |grep nginx
```

Check if nginx listening port 80:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

Comment: What do I do if when I run 
`ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

I get 
`ls: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: @Rich at the end of the `nginx.conf` file there is a line which says `include servers/*;`. In its directory (`/usr/local/etc/nginx/`) make directory named `servers` and in it a file ( for example `localhost.conf`) with server specification.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in my solution.

I had more than one version of nginx running due to previous install attempts and incorrect uninstalls. I deleted all versions and then did a reinstall. Seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks, but it would be much better if you could provide how did you detect multiple versions, as well as how you removed extra ones.